# Microsoft Edge Browser has issues with SharePoint Co-Authoring

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-edge

The Microsoft Edge browser can open a SharePoint 2013 site but I can not open the word documents for co-authoring. The following error message shown when try to open the word document:

[image]

We have no option to open documents using Edge. However, there is no issue when we try to open any word document for co-authoring using IE 11.